# microsoft app center build failure 'bin' not found

Tags: android, react-native

So I am using a standard react-native project, which I am trying to build for android on top of Microsoft App Center.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/

Running the android gradle locally works ok:

`./android/gradlew -p android`

Will indeed work as intended.

But on app center build system they run the following command:

```
[command]/Users/vsts/agent/2.138.6/work/1/s/android/gradlew -p android clean :bin:assembleDebug
```

The build is failing due to the fact that it can't find `:bin` project, in root directory.

Now I am not sure why do they add to the :bin to the build command, and where do this project should come from, or how can I add it to my project?

```
The full error is as follows:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Project 'bin' not found in root project 'MyApp'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 47s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found out what was the issue.
I previously had committed bin folder, with a `gradle.build` file in it.
`App center` detects all `gradle.build` files in the project and try to build them, so thats why app center have added the `:bin` to its command.

After removing the bin folder from git, I had to force `App center` cache to be cleaned, via editing the build configuration triggering `Save & Build` so it will detect that the bin folder is gone.

Comment: Are you referring to the bin folder at `android/app/bin` ?